# How can I set the default device to emulate in Ionic?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, emulation

I'm using Ionic to build an iOS app. Right now I'm testing how it behaves in an iPad 2, but doing this requires me to constantly need to write:

```
ionic emulate ios --target="iPad-2"
```

Is there a way to hard-code this somewhere in the ionic.project file or somewhere else so I can stop manually doing this? Thanks

Comment: may be [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cli-run-task-set-device-of-simulator/1429/4) could be helpful..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going through the same issue and even though this question is a year old but it was the first thing I got through google and couldn't find the answer anywhere else. Here's what I did just because I don't want to use --target="iPhone-7" everytime.

To be clear for anyone who lands here wanting to just run on a specific ios device use the following:

```
ionic run ios --target="iXXX-X"
```

The iXXX-X would be one of the names you get from running
    `ios-sim showdevicetypes`
for example:

```
ionic run ios --target="iPhone-7"
```

I wanted to have a solution to make iPhone-7 my default, so running the following would target iPhone-7 (My original default target is iPhone-SE):

```
ionic run ios
```

It seems like the default is hardcoded and so must be changed in the code.
I found this file: /platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js

In there you'll find a function called deployToSim, I changed it as follows:

```js
function deployToSim(appPath, target) {
  // Select target device for emulator. Default is 'iPhone-6'
  if (!target) {
    return require('./list-emulator-images').run()
      .then(function(emulators) {
        if (emulators.length > 0) {
          target = emulators[0];
        }
        emulators.forEach(function(emulator) {
          // this is the original condition
          // if (emulator.indexOf('iPhone') === 0)  
          // change "iPhone" to the specific model you want, in my case it's iPhone-7
          // Notice the comma in iPhone7, without comma it will take iPhone-7-plus instead
          if (emulator.indexOf('iPhone-7,') === 0) {
            target = emulator;
          }
        });
        events.emit('log', 'No target specified for emulator. Deploying to ' + target + ' simulator');
        return startSim(appPath, target);
      });
  } else {
    return startSim(appPath, target);
  }
}
```